# Properties of the mean residual life function of Zeta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, zeta-functions

Let's say X is Zeta distributed:
$$
p( X = k ) = \frac{k^{-s}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty k^{-s}}
$$

Then, the MRLF (Mean Residual Life Function) of the Zeta distribution is:

\begin{align}
e(u) 
&= E[X - u \mid x > u ] \\
&=\sum_{i=u}^\infty i \frac{i^{-s}}{\sum_{j=u}^\infty j^{-s}} - u \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=u}^\infty i^{1-s}}{\sum_{j=u}^\infty j^{-s}} - u \\
&= \frac{\zeta(s-1, u)}{\zeta(s, u)} - u
\end{align}

Two observations:

1. Plotting the MRLF suggests that it is linear. This is somewhat expected because the Zeta distribution is kind of a discrete version of the Pareto distribution, whose MRLF is linear.

[image]

2. It looks like the slope of the MRLF is some nice function of $s$ (estimated):

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way of showing that these two observations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are just saying that as $n\to \infty$

$$\frac{n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s}}{s-1}-n^{-s}=\int_n^{n+1} (x^{-s}-n^{-s})dx=
\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx=O(s n^{-s-1})$$

So that for $s > 1$ as $u \to \infty$ $$\sum_{n\ge u} n^{-s} \sim\frac{u^{1-s}}{s-1}$$
and for $s > 2$ $$e(u)=\frac{\sum_{n\ge u} n^{1-s}}{\sum_{n\ge u} n^{-s}}-u\sim \frac{\frac{u^{2-s}}{s-2}}{\frac{u^{1-s}}{s-1}}-u = u (\frac{s-2}{s-1}-1)$$

Comment: I am struggling to understand where the first expression comes from and how it leads to the approximation on the second line. I'd be very grateful if you could give a pointer there! Either way, thank you for the help!

Comment: The first line is just saying that $g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^b g'(y)dy$. Then $\sum_{n\ge u} O(n^{-s-1}) = O(u^{-s})$ for a similar reason. @whatamess